# Kotlin adapter pattern: Duplicate method name error on getter function

Tags: kotlin, adapter

Just simple kotlin code to demo Adapter Pattern in Gang of Four Design Pattern. I have a presentation today about this but i can't done it. So sad. I don't want to add much details but they don't allow me to post without much details.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "getRadius" with signature "()I" in class file RoundHole
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (ClassLoader.java:-2) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:756) 
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

Code:

```
interface WorkingWithRound {
    fun getRadius(): Int
}

open class RoundPeg(val radius: Int = 0): WorkingWithRound {
    override fun getRadius() = radius
}

class RoundHole(val radius: Int = 0): WorkingWithRound {
    override fun getRadius() = radius
    
    fun fit(peg: RoundPeg) {
        println(getRadius() >= peg.getRadius())
    }
}

class SquarePeg(val width: Int = 0)

class SquarePegAdapter(val speg: SquarePeg): RoundPeg() {
    override fun getRadius() = (speg.width / 2 * 1.4).toInt()
}


fun main() {
    val hole = RoundHole(5)
    val rpeg = RoundPeg(5)
    hole.fit(rpeg)

    val small_sqpeg = SquarePeg(5)
    val large_sqpeg = SquarePeg(10)
    
    //hole.fit(small_sqpeg) // this won't compile (incompatible types)

    val small_sqpeg_adapter = SquarePegAdapter(small_sqpeg)
    val large_sqpeg_adapter = SquarePegAdapter(large_sqpeg)
    
    hole.fit(small_sqpeg_adapter) // true
    hole.fit(large_sqpeg_adapter) // false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin generates getter method for instance variables, hence the error. Couple of options to fix the issue

- Make `radius` variable private
  `open class RoundPeg(private val radius: Int = 0): WorkingWithRound`
- Mark `radius` with `@JvmField` to instruct compiler not to generate any getter
  `class RoundHole(@JvmField val radius: Int = 0): WorkingWithRound`

Comment: Thanks to you I know more about variable in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be simpler (as well as avoiding the compilation problems) if the interface defined a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html), rather than a getter method:

```
interface WorkingWithRound {
    val radius: Int
}
```

That compiles down to pretty much the same bytecode; but the intent is clearer, and it can then be implemented directly in the constructors:

```
open class RoundPeg(override val radius: Int = 0): WorkingWithRound

class RoundHole(override val radius: Int = 0): WorkingWithRound {
    fun fit(peg: RoundPeg) {
        println(radius >= peg.radius)
    }
}
```

The SquarePegAdapter can be simplified, as it no longer needs to store the `speg` value, but can simply use it as an initialiser for the property:

```
class SquarePegAdapter(speg: SquarePeg): RoundPeg() {
    override val radius = (speg.width / 2 * 1.4).toInt()
}
```

And the rest of the code needs no changes.

Comment: I think your solution is the best for my simple case but for Adapter Patern generally, working with functions in interface is requested so I choose the @sidgate answer. Thank you bro.